# For loop not working, when preceded by "cd /d" (Windows 10, batch file)

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

If I run this in a batch file inside the folder of MP4 files, it works to set the last modified MP4 file as a variable, so it can be played with the default media player:

```
:: Set last modified MP4 file in current folder, as a variable...
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /O:D *.mp4') do @set "newest=%%F"

:: Play the file (opens in default media player)...
"%newest%"
```

If I try to put the following in a batch file outside of the folder of MP4 files, then `cd /d` is ignored by the for loop, it's not working:

```
:: Change to directory containing MP4 files...
cd /d "C:\My Videos"

:: Set last modified MP4 file in "C:\My Videos", as a variable (not working)...
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /O:D *.mp4') do @set "newest=%%F"

:: Copy the MP4 to current folder...
xcopy "%newest%" "%CD%" /i /r /v /k /f /c /h /y >nul 2>&1

:: Change back to current directory
cd /d "%CD%"
```

As you can see, the for loop command is exactly the same in each example. It works in the first, but not in the second.

I tried putting `pause` between each command to see if any errors appear, none do.

I tried taking away the double quotes from around `%CD%` - makes no difference.

I tried putting `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` before the commands, doesn't do anything.

Previously, I tried to specify the folder directly in the FOR loop, by adding `/S` to the DIR command, but that copies the wrong MP4 file for some reason, where the date modified was a nonsensical random date, it was not the last modified MP4. That command went like this:

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /S /O:D "C:\My Videos\*.mp4"') do @set "newest=%%F"
```

That does set an MP4 as a variable... but not the correct one!

Using a batch file inside the folder of MP4 files I know it always works that way.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can shed some light on why this isn't working.

Comment: You can try forfiles and specify its path or use the cd /d option. Both should work.

Comment: Thanks but I can't get it to work. `forfiles /p "%CD%" /m "*.mp4" /c "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /O:D *.mp4') do @set "newest=%%F"`

Comment: don't use %cd%. Use the path itself.

Comment: Nothing's happening with: `forfiles /p "C:\My Videos" /m "*.mp4" /c "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /O:D *.mp4') do @set "newest=%%F"` (or if `/c`, `/m` and `/p` are taken out, or used in other combinations).

Comment: Of cource not. forfiles is not for. Different syntax, different parameters. No IN and DO etc.... You just want to copy. So without using cd, you can use this: `forfiles /p "C:\My Videos" /m *.mp4 /c "cmd /c copy @file ."` the . means current directory.

Comment: OK but it needs `('dir /B /O:D *.mp4')` with it, so the last modified MP4 file is specified. I just gave up in the end and put a batch file in C:\My Videos, then called that. Now I can't get the main batch file to run the rest of the commands after calling it, so I'm just running them as 2 separate batch files. Tried using `exit /b` in the called batch file, doesn't work. Tried `start` etc, it's somehow not returning back to `%~dp0` and is copying GB's worth of MP4's.

Comment: forfiles has a -d property that specify that you only want mp4's that have changed x days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script assumes that `%CD%` will preserve its original value from beginning to end. But that's not how this variable works – it is dynamically updated by the interpreter to always represent the current directory. And after your 1st `cd` command, the path `C:\My Videos` **becomes** the "current" directory.

So your `dir` looks for files in the new location, and your `xcopy` tries to copy the found files back to the same location they were found in, and finally the `cd /d "%CD%"` just says "change to the directory I'm already at". It won't bring you back to the previous location, because at this point %CD% **is** "C:\My Videos".

You need to explicitly record the previous path *before* cd'ing elsewhere, e.g. using `set "PrevDir=%CD%"`.

Comment: It's working, thanks. `xcopy "%newest%" "%PrevDir%"`